# Poisson distribution exercises. Are my answers correct?

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution

> Suppose that a book contains an average of $\lambda$ misprints per
>   page.
>
> (a) What is the probability that 10 pages will contain at most 1
>   misprint?
>
> (b) What is the probability that $n$ pages will contain at most 3
>   misprints?
>
> (c) If the book has $n$ pages, what is the probability that there will
>   be at least $m$ pages that each contain more than $k$ misprints?

My answers:

$X=$ number of misprints per page.

(a) $P(X\leq1), X\sim P(10\lambda)$

(b) $P(X\leq3), X\sim P(n\lambda)$

(c) I'm not sure how to answer this one. Any hint?

Are my answers correct? How can I answer (c)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $X \sim$ Poisson$(\lambda)$, then the number of pages with more than $k$ misprints is distributed binomial$(n, p = P(X > k))$.

Comment: So, the answer to (c) would be $P(Y\geq m), Y\sim$Binomial$(n,p=P(X>k))$, correct?

Comment: That looks good.